# How to install ops library in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have used the following code to install ops lib in Google Colab.

```
!wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/99/d6876608efbc4d934b8855f4cdef83ad96b2f859b514593cf28b843e654a/ops.py-0.1.0a2.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf ops.py-0.1.0a2.tar.gz
%cd ops
!make
!make install
!pip install ops
```

I am getting following error:

> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/40/24e083823c39b485cb5473e62124e9c38cc0fce10f075d3189acf173b56f/ops-0.4.7.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-umrd_yvw/ops/setup.py", line 2, in 
>           from ops import **version** as version
>         File "/tmp/pip-install-umrd_yvw/ops/ops.py", line 38
>           except OSError, error:
>                         ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-umrd_yvw/ops/

Anyone can help to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. the `%cd` command is malformed; the directory actually extracted by tar is named `ops.py-0.1.0a2` not `ops`
2. the tarball in question doesn't have a Makefile, so the `make` and `make install` lines are not useful
3. `ops`' setup.py script uses Python 2 (not Python 3) syntax, raising the `SyntaxError` you pasted.  (i.e. https://pypi.org/project/ops/ lists Python, Python 2.6, and Python 2.7 as its languages, but not any version of Python 3.x like e.g. https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/)
4. By setting runtime type to "Python 2" in notebook settings, a simple `!pip install ops` just works; no need to wget/tar/cd/make.